# SSIS ADO.Net destination not able to see the list of Vertica tables

Tags: ssis, vertica

I'm facing problem when I used SSIS connect to the Vertica destination, it cannot list of Vertica tables.
Could anyone help and suggest?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Very probably, it's the problem of calling SQLColumns() with an empty string or NULL value for the schema.

Instead of looking for `'%'` for the tables, try to look for , for example `'public.%'` .